# How to remove emojies from arabic script in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emoji, arabic

Can anyonr please help me and tell me How to remove emojies from arabic script in the dataframe.
example:

input: يااا واجعوط هذا راه باغي يبدع فالسانكيام‍♀️

output: يااا واجعوط هذا راه باغي يبدع فالسانكيام

I used lots of codes but it deletes everything not English + emojies

Comment: Have you tried this library? https://pypi.org/project/emoji/ -- https://carpedm20.github.io/emoji/docs/#replacing-and-removing-emoji

Comment: yes it deletes all non english letters also

Comment: New Emoji are always being added, so exiting answers that list codepoints become stale relatively quickly, and the distinction between text mode and emoji mode for some. Personally, I would use a regular expression using the regex module (import regex as re) rather than the re module.  Then use the pattern r'\p{Emoji}' to remove Emoji using re.sub().